# Custom font load not working in Expo React native app

Tags: react-native, expo, custom-font

I am getting issue(attached screenshot) while loading & using custom font in react native expo project. I tried all ways to fix but didn't get a proper solution. One surprising thing I found it that when created a new project and used font there by loading, It's working there but not working in project app. What may be issue? I have tried all steps of Restarting server, System, Reinstalling expo app but none of them worked.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import { AppLoading } from 'expo'
import * as Font from 'expo-font'

const fetchFonts = () => {
  return Font.loadAsync({
    'SansPro-regular': require('./assets/fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf'),
    'SansPro-light': require('./assets/fonts/SourceSansPro-Light.ttf'),
    'SansPro-SemiBold': require('./assets/fonts/SourceSansPro-SemiBold.ttf'),
    'SansPro-Bold': require('./assets/fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf')
  })
}

export default function App() {
  const [fontLoaded, setFontLoaded] = useState(false)

  if (!fontLoaded) {
    return (
      <AppLoading startAsync={fetchFonts} onFinish={() => {
        setFontLoaded(true)
      }}
      />
    )
  }

  return (
    <View>
    <Text style = {{fontFamily: 'SansPro-Bold'}}>Welcome to react native</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `async`

```
const fetchFonts = async () => {
  return Font.loadAsync({
    'SansPro-regular': require('./assets/fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf'),
    'SansPro-light': require('./assets/fonts/SourceSansPro-Light.ttf'),
    'SansPro-SemiBold': require('./assets/fonts/SourceSansPro-SemiBold.ttf'),
    'SansPro-Bold': require('./assets/fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf')
  })
}
```

And to use it use `fontFamily` not `fontWeight`

Comment: Well you need to indicate that the function is async by using above method, it's clearly demonstrate in the Expo docs.

Comment: By Mistake, I wrote fontWeight. Updated Question. Still getting issue.

Comment: what issue are you getting? I actually copy and create a new expo project using your code and it work fine using my custom font.

Comment: Yes I mentioned it in question also that surprisingly same code is working when I am using it by creating new project. But it's not working my previously created project. I have to use custom font there. Getting above screenshot issue. What may be problem. Is it regarding some internal node modules? If yes, then how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this

```
expo install 'expo-font'
expo install expo-app-loading
```

replace it

```
import { AppLoading } from 'expo'
import * as Font from 'expo-font'
```

with

```
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
```