# Expo app problem loading especific custon font weights

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-ui-kitten

I have created an `react-native/typescript` app with `expo CLI`, this generate some base code, inlcuding `hooks/useCachedResources` to load any resources or data that we need prior to rendering the app, in my case in this hook I load custom fonts(in particular [Inter Display Font](https://rsms.me/inter/)). I'm experimenting some problems because the app loads only two weights: `regular and medium`, If I try to use `semi-bold` or `bold` this doesnt work and use the san serif font that comes by default.

#### Additional data:

1. The fonts path its ok
2. Expo app doesn't show any error. I have seen in other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62761262/custom-font-load-not-working-in-expo-react-native-app) errors such as `fontFamily "MyFontFamily" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync.` This is not the case.
3. Font family name is in the correct format.
4. I'm using [React Native UI Kitten](https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/guides/branding#typography) and I load the fonts as they suggest in `Advanced Configuration` and change some especific styles.
5. According to some [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38820631/8582246) The out of the box support for custom fonts on Android is a little limited in React Native. It does not support font weights other than normal and bold. So I tried setting `fontWeight: normal` or any of the weights but nothing works.

#### useCachedResources hook

This come by default with `expo init my-app`.

```js
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

// Error reporting service
import { logger } from '@utils';

export function useCachedResources(): boolean {
  const [isLoadingComplete, setLoadingComplete] = useState(false);

  // Load any resources or data that we need prior to rendering the app
  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadResourcesAndDataAsync() {
      try {
        await SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

        // Load fonts
        await Font.loadAsync({
          'inter-display-regular': require('../assets/fonts/InterDisplay-Regular.ttf'),
          'inter-display-medium': require('../assets/fonts/InterDisplay-Medium.ttf'),
          'inter-display-semibold': require('../assets/fonts/InterDisplay-SemiBold.ttf'),
          'inter-display-bold': require('../assets/fonts/InterDisplay-Bold.ttf'),
        });
      } catch (loadCachedResourcesError) {
        logger.log(loadCachedResourcesError);
      } finally {
        setLoadingComplete(true);
        await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
      }
    }

    loadResourcesAndDataAsync();
  }, []);

  return isLoadingComplete;
}
```

#### Consuming the hook in App.tsx

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

import useCachedResources from './hooks/useCachedResources';
import Navigation from './navigation';

// again this comes by defautl expo init command
export default function App(): React.ReactElement | null  {
  const isLoadingComplete = useCachedResources();

  if (!isLoadingComplete) {
    return null;
  } 

  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <Navigation />
      <StatusBar />
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}
```

#### mapping.json: specific UI-Kitten configuration to change font style

I can think that the problem comes from here but the thing is, if there was a problem loading the fonts, either expo would have already thrown an error or the other fonts weights(regular/medium) would not load.

```
{
  "strict": {
    "text-font-family": "inter-display-regular",

    "text-heading-1-font-size": 32,
    "text-heading-1-font-weight": "normal",
    "text-heading-1-font-family": "inter-display-medium",

    "text-paragraph-1-font-size": 16,
    "text-paragraph-1-font-weight": "normal",
    "text-paragraph-1-font-family": "$text-font-family",
  }
}
```

### The problem

I have no idea if the problem comes from `expo`, `ui kitten` or if `inter` font can't be loaded by react native by some other reason.

Answer (score 0):

In your useCachedResources try to remove 'await' keyword from SplashScreen method's:

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();
SplashScreen.hideAsync();